# how to draw rectangles, resized so it will fit my widget

Tags: qt4

I like to draw rectangles in a window, or in a label or whatever, but I like to keep the size small, so that it fits in my mainwindow. I think about a docked window, to start with a size of 500x300.
The size of a rectangle can be 4100x130 or 2800x2070 for example, but that almost goes out of my screen.
What I want is resizing the window and the rectangle should resize also, still fitting in the window.
How can I do this?
Using qt-4.8.4 and also opengl installed.
I made a program for DOS 22 years ago and now it should run under linux. So qt is new to me.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far please.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice there was an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[example removed]

My example was for another question.
because I solved my question a little different.
I will give a better description of my question above

I don't know the screen size of everybodies computer. So it is up to the user how large he makes a window.
Let's say the window size is 600x400
And now I like to draw something in it that is 4000x1300
So it must be scaled to fit into the little window of 600x400, no problem.
But when the user increases the size of the window, perhaps even the size of the drawing is increased, but as I understand it now, there is information missing.
When I have a piece of line from 3 points long and I pull so that it becomes 5 points long, the original line had only 3 points of information, so 2 points must be added from somewhere.
Is it possible to store the entire drawing of 4100x1300 somewhere, and from there it is scaled into my window? So when the windows size is increased, there is made a new scaled copy of the stored image?

Comment: sorry I gave an example for another question that i had.